# Export Step function visual workflows as svg/png

Tags: aws-step-functions

We have no issue using AWS step functions and we can even say that our return of experience is leading to more and more step machines.

Still, we would like to emphasize some of our state machines for internal documentation and would love to find a better way to export step function visual workflows than the typical screenshot. In particular for large state machines.

They are computed as and displayed as `svg` so we tried `svg` export Chrome extensions like:

- [Export SVG with Style](https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwiIoY6g2q_XAhWGLhoKHTYXC_YQFggmMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fchrome.google.com%2Fwebstore%2Fdetail%2Fexport-svg-with-style%2Fdkjdcaddoplepioppogpckelchefhddi%3Fhl%3Den-GB&usg=AOvVaw1niIe0gsQZgijrKaSPGcmk)
- [SVG Export](https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=7&ved=0ahUKEwiIoY6g2q_XAhWGLhoKHTYXC_YQFghGMAY&url=https%3A%2F%2Fchrome.google.com%2Fwebstore%2Fdetail%2Fsvg-export%2Fnaeaaedieihlkmdajjefioajbbdbdjgp%3Fhl%3Den-GB&usg=AOvVaw1IxBvAq66Dlgq5DAkQu3yg)

They both generated black hidden unusable `svg` files.

Is anyone already trying that?

Illustration of a visual workflow with one of the blueprints:

[image: Illustration of a visual workflow with one of the blueprints]

Comment: Hello @herve, could you please send me an e-mail at tsulli@amazon.com, so I can help route your feedback request to the right place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Step Functions console now supports exporting the graph to PNG or SVG. At the top of the state machine viewer, click **Export** > **Export to SVG** or **Export to PNG**.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtD5C.png)

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

After my first response, I realized it was quite obvious, and did not really provide a solution, so after a few hours learning some javascript i came up with a solution to embed the styles AWS uses directly in the `svg` file. I am still having some issues with `svg` sizing, but I hope this is the right path until an official tool is available.

https://codepen.io/tianmarin/full/RwbYpRO

---

**Original response:**

The main issue saving the svg file is that it uses css class:

```html
<svg class="sfn-workflow-graph" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
</svg>
```

If you import the svg code in your documentation page (copy/paste the svg file content) you can add the following class to your site:

```css
svg.sfn-workflow-graph {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}
svg.sfn-workflow-graph .node>.shape {
  stroke: #555555;
  stroke-width: 0.6px;
  fill: #FFFFFF
}
svg.sfn-workflow-graph .node.state.NotYetStarted>.shape, workflow-graph svg.sfn-workflow-graph .node.state.Container>.shape {
  stroke-dasharray: 5 2
}
svg.sfn-workflow-graph .node.state.Failed>.shape, workflow-graph svg.sfn-workflow-graph rect.legend.Failed {
  fill: #DE322F
}
svg.sfn-workflow-graph .node.state.CaughtError>.shape, workflow-graph svg.sfn-workflow-graph rect.legend.CaughtError {
  fill: #FFA500
}
svg.sfn-workflow-graph .node.state.Succeeded>.shape, workflow-graph svg.sfn-workflow-graph rect.legend.Succeeded {
  fill: #2BD62E
}
svg.sfn-workflow-graph .node.state.InProgress>.shape, workflow-graph svg.sfn-workflow-graph rect.legend.InProgress {
  fill: #53c9ed
}
svg.sfn-workflow-graph .node.state.Cancelled>.shape, workflow-graph svg.sfn-workflow-graph rect.legend.Cancelled {
  fill: #dddddd
}
svg.sfn-workflow-graph .node.anchor>.shape {
  fill: #FFDA75
}
svg.sfn-workflow-graph .node.state.hovered:not(.selected):not(.NotYetStarted)>.shape, workflow-graph svg.sfn-workflow-graph .node.selected>.shape {
  stroke: #555555;
  stroke-width: 2px
}
svg.sfn-workflow-graph .node.state.Container.Failed>.shape {
  fill: #EE9592
}
svg.sfn-workflow-graph .node.state.Container.CaughtError>.shape {
  fill: #FFD27F
}
svg.sfn-workflow-graph .node.state.Container.Succeeded>.shape {
  fill: #91EA9A
}
svg.sfn-workflow-graph .node.state.Container.InProgress>.shape {
  fill: #A9E4F7
}
svg.sfn-workflow-graph .node.state.Container.Cancelled>.shape {
  fill: #EEEEEE
}
svg.sfn-workflow-graph marker {
  fill: #555555
}
svg.sfn-workflow-graph path {
  stroke: #555;
  background-color: #555;
  stroke-width: 1px
}
svg.sfn-workflow-graph .node.anchor, workflow-graph svg.sfn-workflow-graph .node.state.NotYetStarted {
  cursor: default
}
svg.sfn-workflow-graph .node.state {
  cursor: pointer
}
svg.sfn-workflow-graph tspan .label {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-shadow: none
}
```

In our case we use [docsify](https://docsify.js.org/#/), and it automatically add svg images like external images (`<img src="file.svg"/>`). So adding the css styles does not help us.